# using python variables as columns in sql statements

Tags: python, sql

I'm writing a small program as part of a school assignment but i've been having trouble with sql statements.
I was wondering if it were possible to use variables defined in the python code in sql statements.

```
X = variable
Y = other_variable
db.execute("""SELECT X FROM TABLE WHERE Value = Y""")
```

like such....
I have read around this froum a bit but I can't understand much of it as I am relatively new to using sql with python

Comment: You can. I'd recommend using PyMYSQL (https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible as an example from a project I recently worked on the syntax would look like this, in this example "word","count" and "partOfSpeech" are all variables coming from the python script.

```
    SQLCommand = ("INSERT INTO [dbo].[WordFrequency]([Word],[Count],[PartOfSpeech])\
    VALUES ("+ "'" + str(word).replace("'","") + "'," + "'" + str(count).replace("'","") + "','" + str(partOfSpeech) + "')")
```

I use the replace function to clean up any tick marks that may break the syntax of the SQL command.